# How to see that $x^3 -8$ can be factored as $(x-2) \cdot (x^2+2x+4)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

What would be the approach towards factoring $x^3 -8$ as $(x-2) \cdot (x^2+2x+4)$? I am not sure I would have been able to readily factor this without seeing the answer. How would one come about this factorization?

Comment: Recall $a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$

Comment: Divide $x^3-8$ by $x-2$. @Sil I believe that Shmuel knows that but wants to know why it is true.

Answer (score 5):

Observe that $2$ is an obvious root. The root-factor theorem then tells you that $x-2$ is a factor. Now just do polynomial division to divide $x^3-8$ by $x-2$. (If you were ever taught synthetic division, that is a “shortcut” accomplishing the same thing.)